# #ifdef to findout if using debian or fedora/RH/centos

Tags: c, linux, path, include

Is there a clean way to differentiate debian include path from RH/fedora/centos one?

I'd like to link with the wbxml2 library but unfortunately the include file si not in the same location depending of the distro.

on debian/ubuntu:

```
    #include <wbxml.h>
```

and on others:

```
    #include <wbxml2/wbxml.h>
```

Does anybody have a clean solution to make this code portable (using #ifdef for example) ?
Thanks

Comment: Manage include directory with `Makefile`/`cmake` instead of preprocessor `#if`?

Comment: actually adding -I/usr/include/wbxml2 in the Makefile solves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [list of provided files for the -dev package](https://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/libwbxml2-dev/filelist) shows, among other things of course:

> `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libwbxml2.pc`

That line is a "package configuration" file for the development package. That means you don't need to care about the absolute location: use the package configuration tool instead.

Add this to your Makefile:

```
CFLAGS += $(pkg-config --cflags libwbxml2)
LDLIBS += $(pkg-config --libs libwbxml2)
```

And you will get the proper paths on all systems using `pkg-config`.

This is the proper, correct and expected way to deal with this issue, and the reason `pkg-config` exists in the first place.